# cookiecutter-django docker PyCharm server config setup

Tags: pycharm, cookiecutter-django

I am using cookiecutter-django with docker.
It works nicely when I manually run the docker server.
I would like to use the `Django server` configurations from PyCharm to quickly run the server.

I would appreciate some help on how to set it up.

As an interpreter I chose: `add remote` and Selected `Docker` from the radio buttons. I left the other configurations as they were.

When I then try to run the server with that config. The default name from cookiecutter-django's setup was "Docker: runserver"
I get this error:

```
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
```

Any ideas on how to fix that? A tutorial on how to setup PyCharm for django-cookiecutter with Docker would be awesome. I am willing to write one if I get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help: [Docker Remote Debugging](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/docs/pycharm/configuration.rst) 
Quite buggy but it works, kind of. If an `communication error` appears press `continue editing` and `OK` again. And you have to restart Pycharm after indexing is done otherwise you can't see your Docker-Demon (View > Tool Windows > Docker).